# Read emails from imap or pop3 server

Tags: python, python-2.7, imap, pop3, imaplib

My task is to read the email using imap or pop3 server address. I am trying to accomplish this task using python. All the sample codes avaliable to do this task throw the error mentioned below

**"error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"**

What might the problem be , Is it my local firewall settings or maybe due to some other reason...????

```
import imaplib

imap_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
imap_user = '****@gmail.com'
imap_pass = '****'

## open a connection 
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)

## login
imap.login(imap_user, imap_pass)
```

and

```
import sys
import chilkat

imap = chilkat.CkImap()

#  Anything unlocks the component and begins a fully-functional 30-day trial.
success = imap.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial")
if (success != True):
    print(imap.lastErrorText())
    sys.exit()

#  Turn on session logging:
imap.put_KeepSessionLog(True)

#  Connect to GMail
#  Use TLS
imap.put_Ssl(True)
imap.put_Port(993)
success = imap.Connect("imap.gmail.com")
if (success != True):
    print(imap.lastErrorText())
    sys.exit()

#  Login
#  Your login is typically your GMail email address.
success = imap.Login("***@gmail.com","*****")
if (success != True):
    print(imap.lastErrorText())
    sys.exit()

#  Select an IMAP mailbox
success = imap.SelectMailbox("Inbox")
if (success != True):
    print(imap.lastErrorText())
    sys.exit()

#  Show the session log.
print(imap.sessionLog())

#  Disconnect from the IMAP server.
success = imap.Disconnect()
```

Comment: Can you post code examples?
We can't know what the source of the timeout is without knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: I bet you're trying to connect on port 143. Gmail only answers on port 993, with SSL wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest doing a simple network sanity test eg: with Telnet as follows:

```
telnet imap.gmail.com 993
```

If networking is happy you should see a response like:

```
Trying 64.233.188.109...
Connected to gmail-imap.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

It also might be worth checking out the gmail help page for IMAP

https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/7875

Comment: **Connecting To imap.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 993: Connect failed**    ---- am getting the following error....reason why this is happening....any suggestions?

Comment: More than likely your firewall is not allowing outgoing connections on port 993, this is typical for an enterprise setup where, for security reasons they may want to restrict how emails enter into the organisation.

If this is a home setup then you might want to check your router web administration page.

I'm assuming you can ping imap.gmail.com?

To figure out your firewall's address you might like to look into traceroute (or tracert under windows) This can show you all of the network hops where the issue might be happening.